# Add Bootstrap4 via npm to a Symfony4 project

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, symfony4

I am pretty new to Symfony and NPM, Composer etc. I set up my symfony project and installed Bootstrap 4 via NPM

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Now the bootstrap files are located in the "node_modules/bootstrap" folder.
How can I include this sources correctly in my base.html.twig?

```
<link href="{{ asset('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't know if that is the correct way. As I said, I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "import" in your js file to import css.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

https://reactstrap.github.io/